# Django is it better to check user.is_authenticated in views.py or in template?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-templates

I have a homepage, which I want to display a login form when user is not logged in or display a list of items belong to that user if he/she already logged in.

So far I came up with 2 methods:

1. Check whether user is authenticated in views.py and render corresponding view (in my *views.py*):

   ```
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       return render(request, 'items.html')
   else
       return render(request, 'login.html')
   ```
2. Check directly in template and generate corresponding HTML for each case (in my *index.html*):

   ```
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       HTML for my items list
   {% else %}
       HTML for my login form
   {% endif %}
   ```

#### Question

So which method is better for handling this? Are those methods differ much in performance? Is there any standard that we should handling these in **views.py** or in template itself?

Comment: I would keep the logic in the views and use separate and specific page templates for the authentication (login/logout). That is not only cleaner, but allows you to redirect the user when they try to access a resource anonymously directly. In that case, you can redirect them to the login page adding a url parameter that will be used to take them back to the resource page after they authenticate successfully.

Comment: Honestly I prefer the first method also because my code is much more cleaner this way. But how about performance? Does moving the check and generate view directly in template will save some load for the backend?

Comment: In my opinion, the middleware is more suitable for that task: [middleware example](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/)

Comment: The first one would probably work if you want to render a whole different page for different user states. But what if you just want to change a part of a page? Say a logged in dropdown on the navbar?

Comment: Yes, exactly, to change only a small part of the page I'm still using user.is_authenticated inside template. But my question was to render mostly an entire page, separating those templates for different purposes would be much more cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a big performance difference. What's most important is how much you should stick to [`MVC`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) pattern.

A `template` is meant to just display some sort of data that the `view` provides. Any kind of logic like deciding what kind of data to show based on requester's state should always be implemented by the view. Thus, you should move your logic into view function for the cleanness of your design.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I tried to upvote your answer but I didn't have enough reputation to do that. I will come back and vote when i am able to. :)

Comment: While I somehow agree with you, I don't think you can avoid using logic in your `template` as the `view` doesn't know anything about it. Ex. adding a logged in user dropdown on the navbar. I wonder how you would control this with `views` without using logic in the `template`. If there is such a way, please share it.

PS. not sarcastic. Seriously if there's such a way to do it I want to know.

Comment: @DigitalDouble You are talking about changing the way the "data" will look like. Thus, it is perfectly normal to do that kind of thing in the template. OP's example was about rendering different templates based on user's state, in other words, data. So I said, that kind of thing should be handled in the view, not in the template as you are deciding which data to show, not how it will look like.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

> Logic should be in your python code, not your template as much as possible. Due to **maintenance and future-proof reasons**.

#### Elaborate

- **Code quality**: you can **test your business logic** when it's in your python not when it's in templates. The former improve your code quality and your value as a developer ;
- **Future-proof**: you don't know which technology your application is going to use in the future, so avoiding tech-mingling will help you when upgrading it (you will be able to upgrade at different pace).
- [Separation of concerns principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): do you want a code that is a spaghetti plate, where you can't refactor a thing without impacting ten others?
- **Code legacy**: you don't know who is going to work on your code neither which code you're going to work on. Don't make it hard for them (it would probably be your future self) ;
- **Clean code**: that express itself in a single dialect is always better that mixing languages ;
- **Knowledge scope**: front-end is *often* the responsibility of people with low programming skills (HTML/CSS are declarative) and you don't want them to mess with your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your html. If you want to change only a little part of your code based on the condition, check inside a template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
{% else %}
    <a href="/path/to/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

But if `items.html` and `login.html` are different and big templates, you should definitely do the login inside your view.